# Change the background color of a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uicolor, uiactivityviewcontroller

In iOS 7, the standard `UIActivityViewController` has a transluscent whitish background. On the contrary my app has a dark theme. It looks terrible when the white `UIAcitivityViewController` pops up on the dark app background.

**Is there a way to change the background color of a** `UIAcitivityViewController`**?**

I have tried
`activityVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]`, but this makes the whole screen black, not just the area occupied by the `UIAcitivity` icons like the standard white background.

[image: screenshot of a UIActivityViewController]

Answer (score 1):

Swift answer to force an UIActivityViewController into dark mode (the same works for light mode as well, just replace `.dark` with `.light`):

```
activityViewController.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark

// these two are needed for the modification of the Save to Files dialog
UINavigationBar.appearance().overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
UITableView.appearance().overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIActivityViewController class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Comment: This has the same effect as `activityVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]`. It makes everything black, not just the lower part with the icons. In addition when I choose a color with alpha i.e. 0.5 it looks weird because I can see the frames of the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Although my solution seems a little unstable, it works with both iOS7 & iOS8. It also won't crash your app if something should suddenly change;

```
UIActivityViewController *aVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://example.com"] applicationActivities:nil];
id targetView = [[[[[[[[[[[aVC.view.subviews lastObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject] subviews] firstObject];
if ([targetView respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)])
{
    UIColor *targetColor = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) ? [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] : [UIColor redColor];
    [targetView setBackgroundColor:targetColor];
}
```

What it looks like in the simulator, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All I got was change the background of the main view. No success trying to change the color of the label inside it.

```
let aType = NSClassFromString("_UIShareExtensionRemoteViewController") as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [aType.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score -2):

```
socialActivityPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityView];
[socialActivityPopover setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.